# How to get the element which initiated the event in a series of events?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Actually there would be two questions,

**The scenario is**

The form contains three submit buttons, when i'm clicking one of those button the submit event is get triggered, then the first event is `click` but i'm not capturing this. The second event is form's `submit` which is the one i'm capturing.

The code is

```
$('#search-main a').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#search-advanced').remove();
    var target = $(this).attr('href');
    var res = $.get(target, function(data){
        $('body').append($(data).find('#search-advanced'));
        $('#search-advanced').addClass('row reveal-modal');
        $('#search-advanced')
        .css('top', 80)
        .css('border-radius' , '5px')
        .css('padding-left' , '0px')
        .css('padding-right' , '0px');

        $('#search-advanced').on('submit', 'form' ,function(e){
            var params = $('#search-advanced form').serialize();

            console.log(e);
            console.log(params);
            $.get(target, params, function(data){
                $('#search-advanced form').html($(data).find('#search-advanced form').html());
                $('#search-advanced input[name="select_filter"]').remove();
            });
            return false;
        });

        $('#search-advanced input[name="select_filter"]').remove();
        $('#search-advanced').on('change', '#categoryDropdown', function(){
            $('#search-advanced form').trigger('submit');
        });

        $('#search-advanced').append('<a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>');
        $('#search-advanced').reveal({
            animation: 'fade', 
            closeOnBackgroundClick: false
        });
    });
});
```

Since the JQuery documentation says

> Only "successful controls" are serialized to the string. No submit
>   button value is serialized since the form was not submitted using a
>   button

I was unable to get the button values using `serialize()`

**Question one is**

> How to get the button attributes which initiated the submit?

I approached in a different way as workaround of this, which was

- First capturing the click event
- Get the attributes
- Pass the attributes as event extra parameters

The modified code is

```
$('#search-advanced').on('submit', 'form' ,function(e){
    var params = $('#search-advanced form').serialize();

    console.log(e.data);
    console.log(params);
    $.get(target, params, function(data){
        $('#search-advanced form').html($(data).find('#search-advanced form').html());
        $('#search-advanced input[name="select_filter"]').remove();

        if(typeof $('input[name="one_more"]') !== 'undefined'){
            var oldOneButton = $('input[name="one_more"]');
            var newOneButton = oldOneButton.clone();
            newOneButton.attr('type', 'button');
            newOneButton.insertBefore(oldOneButton);
            oldOneButton.remove();
        }

        if(typeof $('input[name="remove_filter"]').attr('name') !== 'undefined'){
            var oldRemoveButton = $('input[name="remove_filter"]');
            var newRemoveButton = oldRemoveButton.clone();
            newRemoveButton.attr('type', 'button');
            newRemoveButton.insertBefore(oldRemoveButton);
            oldRemoveButton.remove();
        }
    });
    return false;
});

$('#search-advanced input[name="select_filter"]').remove();
$('#search-advanced').on('change', '#categoryDropdown', function(){
    $('#search-advanced form').trigger('submit');
});

$('#search-advanced').on('click', 'input[name="one_more"]', function(){
    console.log($(this).attr('name'));
    var name = $(this).attr('name');
    var value = $(this).attr('value');
    $('#search-advanced form').trigger('submit', {name:value});
});
```

I changed the type attribute because it triggered the submit two times.

The problem is the `console.log(e.data);` prints `undefined` instead of the passed object.

**Second question is**

> Why the `e.data` is `undefined`?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can try [`event.relatedTarget`](http://api.jquery.com/event.relatedTarget/) to get the button that was clicked on to submit the form. I've never used it myself, but I think it should work.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist nope, it also undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To capture the button, [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JjZdD/2/)

```
    $("#frm").on("click","button",function(){
       alert(this.id);

    }).on("submit",function(e){
        console.log("submit");
        return false;
    });​
```

Comment: That doesn't give you access to the button that was clicked in the `submit` event handler, though.

Comment: Yeah I just try to answer one of your problem  "the first event is click but i'm not capturing this". I do not think you can get the button by event object in submit event as it is triggered by the form.

Comment: Or you can do something like `console.log($(this).find("button:hover"));` to get the button. But I think it is not a good idea....

Comment: Actually i'm not aware of this kind of chaining of events, @Willy you saved my day. This answer helped me a lot to solve and re-factor. I found a solution for the second approach too. I'll post the working answer, while accept this. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The working solution, contains the answer for both questions

```
$('#search-main a').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#search-advanced').remove();
    var target = $(this).attr('href');
    var res = $.get(target, function(data){
        $('body').append($(data).find('#search-advanced'));
        $('#search-advanced').addClass('row reveal-modal');
        $('#search-advanced')
        .css('top', 80)
        .css('border-radius' , '5px')
        .css('padding-left' , '0px')
        .css('padding-right' , '0px');

        var clickedButtonName;
        var clickedButtonVal;
        $('#search-advanced input[name="select_filter"]').remove();
        $('#search-advanced').on('change','#categoryDropdown', function(){
            $('#search-advanced form').trigger('submit', {'select_filter':'Select Filter'});
        }).on('click', 'input.button', function(){
            clickedButtonName = $(this).attr('name');
            clickedButtonVal = $(this).attr('value');
        }).on('submit', 'form' ,function(e, attr){
            var params = $('#search-advanced form').serialize();

            if(typeof attr !== 'undefined'){
                var key = Object.keys(attr);
                params += '&'
                + key[0]
                + '='
                + attr[key[0]];
            }

            if(typeof clickedButtonName !== 'undefined' && typeof clickedButtonVal !== 'undefined'){
                params += '&'
                + clickedButtonName
                + '='
                + clickedButtonVal;
            }
            $.get(target, params, function(data){
                $('#search-advanced form').html($(data).find('#search-advanced form').html());
                $('#search-advanced input[name="select_filter"]').remove();
            });
            return false;
        });

        $('#search-advanced').append('<a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>');
        $('#search-advanced').reveal({
            animation: 'fade', 
            closeOnBackgroundClick: false
        });
    });
});
```